# Clearing a JFrame without using paint(Graphics g)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint, event-dispatch-thread

I am trying to clear all of the contents of a JFrame so I can display something else.  I don't want to use the paint(Graphics g) method because I am trying to clear the screen from within a timer and I'm unable to use

```
clearRect( int , int , int , int )
```

This is what I have already tried but the IDE gives an error and it doesn't clear the screen.

EDIT: my new code

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("...");
/*...*/

Timer timer = new Timer(5000, new RemoveContentsTask(frame));
timer.start();

/*...*/

public abstract class RemoveContentsTask implements Runnable {

private JFrame frame;

public RemoveContentsTask(JFrame frame) {
    this.frame = frame;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    frame.getContentPane().removeAll();


     System.out.println("Timer"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: well, what is the error?

Comment: 1- Don't use `java.util.Timer`, instead use `javax.swing.Timer`. 2- What do you have on your frame?  If it's just other components you should use `JFrame#getContentPane#removeAll`

Comment: `this.getContentPane().removeAll()`, in this context, `this` refers to the `TimerTask`, not your frame

Answer (score 2):

1. You should be using a `javax.swing.Timer` instead of `java.util.Timer` to make sure you are honoring the single thread nature of Swing and making your updates within the EDT.
2. In the context of you question, `this.getContentPane().removeAll()`, `this` is referring to the instance of `TimerTask`

Instead you should try something more like...

```
import javax.swing.Timer;
/*...*/

JFrame frame = new JFrame("...");
/*...*/

Timer timer = new Timer(5000, new RemoveContentsTask(frame));
timer.start();

/*...*/

public class RemoveContentsTask implements Runnable {

    private JFrame frame;

    public RemoveContentsTask(JFrame frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
    }
}
```

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Comment: I cant seem to get that to work it gives me this error and doesn't clear the screen or start the Timer.    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous ctor sym type: <any>
 at web.game.Base.main(Base.java:159)